# Matplotlib Qt5Agg backend not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, cx-freeze

I have written a Python 3.6 program that reads a .txt file of UTM coordinates, sorts them into counterclockwise order, displays the coordinates on a graph using matplotlib, and then writes the coordinates to a .txt file on the desktop. It works fine when I run it in spyder, which is the IDE that I have been using, but when I convert it to an exe using cx_Freeze (by building my python file) and try to run it, I get the following error:
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg'
I have tried installing the Qt5 backend by doing:
    pip install PyQt5
As well as updating cx_Freeze. Any help would be much appreciated. I am still a beginner with Python as well as programming in general so I apologize if I was not clear enough in my explantion. Below is my code for my main Python script

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as math
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import time


def findFilename():
    root = tk.Tk()
    #root.withdraw()
    filename = askopenfilename()
    root.destroy()
    return(filename)

def findSize(cnt, filename):
    #number of lines in file
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            cnt = cnt+1;
    return cnt;

def findChar(filename):
    file = open(filename, "r")

    char = ""
    lines = file.read()

    if(lines.find(" ") == -1):
        char = ","
    else:
        char = " "

    return(char)


def inputArr(cnt, arrX, arrY, arrZ, filename, char):
    file = open(filename, "r")
    num1 = 0
    num2 = 0
    num3 = 0
    place1 = 0
    place2 = 0
    place3 = 0



    for i in range(0, cnt):
        num = file.readline()
        place1 = num.find(char)
        num1 = num[:place1]
        num = num[place1 + 1:]
        place2 = num.find(char)
        num2 = num[:place2]
        num = num[place2+1:]
        place3 = num.find(char)
        num3 = num[:place3]

        arrX.append(float(num1))
        arrY.append(float(num2))
        arrZ.append(float(num3))

    return(arrX, arrY, arrZ)

def drawPath(arrX, arrY, label, cnt):
    plt.plot(arrX, arrY, '-ok', color = 'red')

    plt.xlabel("X coordinates")
    plt.ylabel("Y coordinates")
    plt.title("Loop path")
    plt.show()


    for i in range(0,cnt):
        label.append(str(i))

    for i, txt in enumerate(label):
        plt.annotate(txt, (arrX[i], arrY[i]))


def findCenter(arrX, arrY, cnt):
    xCenter = 0
    yCenter = 0

    for i in range(0,cnt):
        xCenter += arrX[i]
        yCenter += arrY[i]


    xCenter /= cnt
    yCenter /= cnt
    return(xCenter, yCenter)

def moveToCenter(arrX, arrY, arrX1, arrY1, xCenter, yCenter, cnt):
    for i in range(0,cnt):
        arrX1.append(arrX[i] - xCenter)
        arrY1.append(arrY[i] - yCenter)

    return(arrX1, arrY1)

def calculateTheta(arrX1, arrY1, arrTheta, cnt):
    for i in range(0,cnt):
        arrTheta.append(math.atan2(arrY1[i], arrX1[i]))

  #  print(arrTheta[0])
    return(arrTheta)

def sortPoints(arrTheta, arrX, arrY, arrZ, cnt):
    minimum = 0

    for i in range(0,cnt-1):
        minimum = i
        for j in range(i + 1, cnt):
            if(arrTheta[j] < arrTheta[minimum]):
                minimum = j
        arrTheta[minimum], arrTheta[i] = arrTheta[i], arrTheta[minimum]
        arrX[minimum], arrX[i] = arrX[i], arrX[minimum]
        arrY[minimum], arrY[i] = arrY[i], arrY[minimum]
        arrZ[minimum], arrZ[i] = arrZ[i], arrZ[minimum]

def writeFile(arrX, arrY, arrZ, cnt, char):
    moment = time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d__%H_%M_%S",time.localtime())

    file = open("C:\\Users\\natha\\Desktop\\sorted" + str(moment) + ".txt", "w")
    num = ""

    for i in range(0,cnt):
        if(i < 10):
            num = "0"
        else:
            num = ""

        file.write("<" + "L" + num + str(i) + ">" + " " + str(arrX[i]) + char + 
                   str(arrY[i]) + char + str(arrZ[i]) + char + "\n")




def main():

    cnt = 0
    arrX = []
    arrY = []
    arrZ = []
    label = []
    arrX1 = []
    arrY1 = []
    arrTheta = []
    xCenter = 0
    yCenter = 0
    char = ""

    filename = findFilename()
    char = findChar(filename)

    cnt = findSize(cnt, filename)

    findChar(filename)
    inputArr(cnt, arrX, arrY, arrZ, filename, char)

    xCenter, yCenter = findCenter(arrX, arrY, cnt)
    arrX1, arrY1 = moveToCenter(arrX, arrY, arrX1, arrY1, xCenter, yCenter, cnt)

    arrTheta = calculateTheta(arrX1, arrY1, arrTheta, cnt)
    #arrX, arrY, arrZ = randomPoints(arrX, arrY, arrZ, cnt)
    sortPoints(arrTheta, arrX, arrY, arrZ, cnt)

    writeFile(arrX, arrY, arrZ, cnt, char)
    drawPath(arrX, arrY, label, cnt)


main()
```

As well as my setup.py file

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os.path


os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\natha\Anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\natha\Anaconda3\tcl\tk8.6'

additional_mods = ['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format']
setup(name='loopProgram', 
      version='0.4', 
      description='xyz script',
      options = {'build_exe': {'includes': additional_mods}},
      executables = [Executable('loopProgram.py')]
    )
```

Comment: Did you try "TkAgg" backend? I'm not 100% sure but "TkAgg" seems more suited for a Tk app.

Answer (score 5):

Install missing matplotlib qt5 backend
     sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib-qt5

Get the Matplotlib config file path:
    python
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
    u'/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc'
In the config file, change the backend to qt5agg
    vi /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc

Change the line to :

backend : qt5agg

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. When I opened the matplotlibrc file, my backend was qt5agg by default. It still does not work. I am using windows 10, if that helps at all.

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package python-matplotlib-qt5
` on ubuntu20.04

Comment: First of all thanks @Neeraj Nair  (For anyone comes in this way) in fedora this will work. `dnf install python3-matplotlib-qt5`

Answer (score 3):

For OpenSUSE I found that the above answers didn't work. I tried all of the various backends, and nothing show'd. I was getting no error output from the script running and furthermore the plot.show() function wasn't even blocking the console. `plot.savefig()` worked without issue when used properly, as outlined in [this thread](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6306/)

[This link](https://gist.github.com/necojackarc/124b9e6a131b5dcf22ef2e22572ce97d) showed that I needed to add `tk-devel` before I installed `matplotlib`. Using Zypper I installed `tk-devel`, uninstalled `python3-matplotlib`, reinstalled matplotlib, and that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to add the following line

```
import matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg
```

in your main Python script (or in any other appropriate module used in your script) to "force" cx_Freeze to include this module?

Comment: It might be helpful to clarify how cx_Freeze decides what to include (and why qt5agg is a "hidden" import in this case).

Comment: @SNygard I completely agree with you and I don't know the answer. While developing an application I noticed that I need to explicitly `import matplotlib.backends.backend_ps`to be able to save a plot as postscript in the frozen application. Other backends such as PNG are included by cx_Freeze without need of an explicit import.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I faced this Problem with Spyder 5 lately.
I am using OpenSUSE and  I solved this problem just by installing python38-matplotlib-qt5 with

```
zypper in python38-matplotlib-qt5
```

Check your python version first though !!!
this will probably only work with python3.8 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue occurred to me also, try reinstalling matplolib

`pip3 uninstall matplotlib`

then

`pip3 install matplotlib`

which solved my issue.